# how to search and loop array of object for particular key using recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have a array of objects

- Some objects have id and some are not
- those having id can present with either "split" or "relation" key not both
- inside split there can be another split or relation
- now I need to read all relation present by digging deeply

I need output like below:

```
let _rel = [
    {"relation": "a"},
    {"relation": "b"}
]
```

```
// my try which is not working 
const getRelations = (arr, _rel=[]) => {
    for(let {uuid, relations, split} of arr){
        if(uuid) {
            if(relations) [..._rel, relations]
            else if(split) {
                getRelations(split)
            }
        }
    }
    return _rel    
}
getRelations(arr)
```

Input:

```
let arr = [
    { "start_offset": 0 },
    {
        "uuid": "100",
        "relations": [
            {
                "relation": "a",
            }
        ]
    },
    { "start_offset": 355 },
    {
        "uuid": "200",
        "split": [
            {
                "uuid": "300",
                "split": [
                    {
                        "uuid": "400",
                        "relations": [
                            {
                                "relation": "b",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "500",
            }
        ],
    },
    { "start_offset": 689 }
]

// my try which is not working 
const getRelations = (arr, _rel = []) => {
    for (let { uuid, relations, split } of arr) {
        if (uuid) {
            if (relations) [..._rel, relations]
            else if (split) {
                getRelations(split)
            }
        }
    }
    return _rel
}
getRelations(arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An one-liner (avoid any intermediate arrays and pass the result array as an argument to a recursive function):

```js
const data = [{ start_offset: 0 }, { uuid: "100", relations: [{ relation: "a" }] }, { start_offset: 355 }, { uuid: "200", split: [{ uuid: "300", split: [{ uuid: "400", relations: [{ relation: "b" }] }] }, { uuid: "500" }] }, { start_offset: 689 }];

const getRelations = (items, out = []) => (items.forEach(item => item.split ? getRelations(item.split, out) : item.relations && out.push(...item.relations)), out);

console.log(getRelations(data));
```

```
` Chrome/119
-----------------------------------------------------------
Alexander      1.00x  |  x10000000  567  571  573  589  590
Nina Scholz   11.09x  |   x1000000  629  630  633  648  659
-----------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const data = [{ start_offset: 0 }, { uuid: "100", relations: [{ relation: "a" }] }, { start_offset: 355 }, { uuid: "200", split: [{ uuid: "300", split: [{ uuid: "400", relations: [{ relation: "b" }] }] }, { uuid: "500" }] }, { start_offset: 689 }];

//@benchmark Nina Scholz

const fn = ({ split, relations }) => split
        ? split.flatMap(fn)
        : relations || [],
    getRelations = array => array.flatMap(fn);

getRelations(data);


//@benchmark Alexander 
{
const getRelations = (items, out = []) => (items.forEach(item => item.split ? getRelations(item.split, out) : item.relations && out.push(...item.relations)), out);
getRelations(data);

}


/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a check and return a flat array of `relations` or an empty array.

```js
const
    data = [{ start_offset: 0 }, { uuid: "100", relations: [{ relation: "a" }] }, { start_offset: 355 }, { uuid: "200", split: [{ uuid: "300", split: [{ uuid: "400", relations: [{ relation: "b" }] }] }, { uuid: "500" }] }, { start_offset: 689 }],
    fn = ({ split, relations }) => split
        ? split.flatMap(fn)
        : relations || [],
    getRelations = array => array.flatMap(fn);

console.log(getRelations(data));
```

Comment: this Null coalescing operator wont work in many projects including mine i.e react. but, thank you

Comment: you could replace it with logical OR `||`.

Comment: This is so weird react doesn't support flatMap also. I just found out. but thank you

Comment: @VikasAcharya `Array.prototype.flatMap` is from Javascript, you should check the js version in your project.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of changes:

1- When you have relations, push the `{ "relation": relations }`
object into the `_rel` array.

2- When you have `split`, recursively call `getRelations` with the split array and pass the existing `_rel` array.

Now, the relations array should be correctly populated with the desired output.

```js
const getRelations = (arr, _rel = []) => {
  for (let {
      uuid,
      relations,
      split
    } of arr) {
    if (uuid) {
      if (relations) {
        _rel.push({
          "relation": relations
        });
      } else if (split) {
        getRelations(split, _rel);
      }
    }
  }
  return _rel;
};


const arr = [{
    uuid: "1",
    relations: "a",
    split: [{
      uuid: "2",
      relations: "b"
    }]
  },
  {
    uuid: "3",
    split: [{
      uuid: "4",
      relations: "c"
    }]
  },
];

const relations = getRelations(arr);
console.log(relations);
```